# Error in SQL Query: Retrieving Users with Duplicate Email Addresses Registered in the Last 30 Days

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, apache-age

I am trying to retrieve data from `public.users` tables and this the query I am using but I am not able to retrieve, what i actually require:

```
WITH duplicates AS (
    SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS duplicate_count
    FROM public.users
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, d.duplicate_count
FROM public.users u
JOIN duplicates d ON u.email = d.email
WHERE u.registration_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days';
```

I am trying to use the concept of Common Table Expression (CTE) named "duplicates" to find all email addresses that have more than one occurrence in the "public.users" table.
I might be making some mistake, because despite having duplicate emails I am not able to fetch them using this particular query.
I will be grateful if you could help!

Comment: What is the problem with this query? what is the output or error log? Query seems pretty simple and should work.

Comment: Maybe your duplicate emails aren't meeting the requirement in your WHERE clause with the registration date. Based on the title, you may want to move that restriction to your CTE.

Comment: Do you want to find *duplicate email addresses* or *users with duplicate email addresses*. Important difference. Duplicates with more than one entry in the last 30 days, or duplicates with just one entry in the last 30 days and at least one more earlier, too? Also, what is the exact definition of the column `registration_date`? And your Postgres version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to get emails with entries during the last 30 days and a duplicate from *any* time:

```sql
SELECT email, count(*) AS duplicate_count
FROM   public.users
GROUP  BY email
HAVING count(*) > 1
AND    max(u.registration_date) >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
```

Also assuming `registration_date` is an actual `date`.

If the table is big, with lots of older data, and duplicates often occur in close proximity, this more elaborate query might perform better:

```sql
WITH email_cnt AS (
   SELECT email, count(*) AS duplicate_count
   FROM   public.users
   WHERE  u.registration_date >= CURRENT_DATE - 30
   GROUP  BY email
   )
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, e.duplicate_count  -- local dupes
FROM   email_cnt e
JOIN   public.users u USING (email)
WHERE  e.duplicate_count > 1

UNION  -- not UNION ALL, because both may apply
SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, e.duplicate_count  -- remote dupes
FROM   email_cnt e
JOIN   public.users u USING (email)
WHERE  e.duplicate_count = 1
AND    EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM public.users u1
   WHERE  u1.email = e.email
   AND    u1.registration_date < CURRENT_DATE - 30
   );
```

This time also including details for the latest entry.

Answer (score 0):

The key issues in your query:

The CTE itself needs the filter on registration_date, not the outer query, to only consider recent emails for counting duplicates.

When joining the CTE back to the users table, you again need the registration_date filter in the join condition to only get recent duplicates.

```
    WITH duplicates AS (
    SELECT email, COUNT(*) AS duplicate_count
    FROM public.users
    WHERE registration_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
    GROUP BY email
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1)
    SELECT u.user_id, u.user_name, d.duplicate_count
    FROM public.users u
    JOIN duplicates d ON u.email = d.email
    WHERE u.registration_date >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days';
```

Here is an example for you to understand better:

Let's say there is an email that appears 3 times total in the table. But only 2 of them are within the last 30 days.

If you don't filter in the CTE, it would count 3 occurrences and include that email in the duplicate list.

But in the outer query, only 2 of those rows would match the date filter. So you'd end up with incorrect data.

By filtering in both parts, you ensure the logic is restricted to the right date range in all steps.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is with the `GROUP BY` clause in the CTE.

you are grouping by the `email` column, but you are not including the `user_id` or `user_name` in the `SELECT` statement of the CTE.

this could cause unexpected results when you later join the CTE with the `public.users` table.